# Javascript or css for clickable menu and horizontal nav

Tags: javascript, html, css, nav

I want to make a horizontal nav which is not automatically visible. I want an image(?) to be clickable so that the menu can be opened and closed by it.

This is the code that I have for the moment. I've put the img in an `li`, because of the layout, I don't know if this is the right way to do it.

```
<header>
    <nav id="hoofdnavigatie">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/mobilebutton.png" alt="menu"/></a></li>
            <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="recept.html">Recept</a></li>
            <li><a href="bestel.html">Bestel</a></li>
            <li><a href="kok.html">Kok</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

After clicking the menu
[image: After clicking the menu]

Before clicking the menu

[image: Before clicking the menu]

Comment: _what javascript or css have you tried?_

Comment: I really have no idea how to start and I don't know how to search for it on the internet because I don't know how to call it. When I try to search I can only find things such as a JavaScript dropdown menu but not what I'm looking for..

Comment: @LottePothé I'm added an answer below,check it and if it's useful don't forget to tick it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that using **js**

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
    var k = document.getElementsByClassName("menu");
    for(i=0;i<k.length;i++){
        if(k[i].style.display == "none"){
           k[i].style.display = "inline-block";
          }  
            else{
                k[i].style.display = "none";
            }
    }
});
```

```css
ul,li{
  list-style:none;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-right:5px;
  }
li{
  display:inline-block;
  }
img{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  }
ul{
  background:green;
  border:2px solid #000;
  padding:10px;
  }
a {
    color: yellow;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover 
{
     color:yellow; 
     text-decoration:none; 
     cursor:pointer;  
}
#btn{
  cursor:pointer;
  }
```

```html
<header>
    <nav id="hoofdnavigatie">
        <ul>
            <li id="btn"><a href="#"><img  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIYr8.jpg" alt="menu"/></a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a href="recept.html">Recept</a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a href="bestel.html">Bestel</a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a href="kok.html">Kok</a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Javascript to toggle some classes & accordingly apply it into your CSS.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```js
$('.nav-opener').on('click', function() {
  $($(this)).toggleClass('open');
  $('nav').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.content-holder {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav {
  display: none;
}

nav.open {
  display: block;
}

.nav-opener {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  padding: 8px;
}

.nav-opener.open {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.nav-opener .bar {
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #777;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.nav-opener .bar:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-holder">
  
  <div class="nav-opener">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  </div>
  <nav id="hoofdnavigatie">
          <ul>
              <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="recept.html">Recept</a></li>
              <li><a href="bestel.html">Bestel</a></li>
              <li><a href="kok.html">Kok</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
  
</div>
```

Hope this helps!